is Arton bank is a legit bank
I got a Grant Release Approval (G.R.A) Code from donation board called Alwaleed Bin Talal International Charity and asked me to FILL THE GRANT FORM  AND CONTACT THE ARTON BANK FOR PAYMENT via
Email: info@arton-bnk.com
This bank reply to me with way to create account by its online panking web page to fill my home bank account(IBAN/swift code) to make inter. Transfer but then asked my to apply and pay for a COT code for each process. Do you think it is scam?
This bank ask a COT code for money transfer

This is definitely a scam. Without even knowing anything about the bank, everything you have said is covered in so many red flags you could make a whole parade out of them. Google "COT code" and you will find more results than you could ever wish for.

"Google COT code" isn't such a good advise, because the scammer have started to seed misinformation on the Internet that it is indeed a thing. For example, in this German-language Q&A community where someone claims to be a lawyer and tries to tell people that a COT code is required to get money from the UK to Austria and that it would be expensive.
